# Text Decoration in HTML Email (non-link)

Tags: html, css, email

Ok, I am working on a fairly basic HTML email.  All I would like is for the underline color to show up on all email clients the same.  I would like it to be white. However, on some email clients (mostly on apple products) it shows up black.

I have used the HTML underline attribute and I have used inline css (text-decoration and text-decoration-color) but the underline is still black.

Does anyone know any workarounds to ensure the underline color is white in all email clients?

Comment: have you checked supports ? http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color an average work around would be to use an inline element and use a bottom border

Comment: You deleted your scraper question before I was able to post this: I seem to recall that import.io has a scraper feature, perhaps that would be enough to submit forms etc? There is a free tier that would probably be enough for you.

Comment: You could also do it yourself with PhantomJS, but you'd need to have an understanding of how scrapers work, and what things to do to avoid being blocked by a remote host.

Comment: Thanks again halfer, you are very helpful in your responses and I truly appreciate it.  This gives me a good starting point to do some research.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `text-decoration-color`property is [not yet supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color#Browser_compatibility) so the underline just adapts the text color.

Instead of `text-decoration: underline` you could use a `border-bottom: 1px solid white` which looks similar. Another (hacky) possibility is using a box-shadow for an underline. Here's how: https://walterebert.com/blog/underlined-links-css3-box-shadow-text-shadow/

Answer (score 0):

As commented:

---

check support before use :)

[can I use ?](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color)
[image]

**an average work around is to use an inline element**:

```css
p span {
  border-bottom:1px tomato solid;
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<span> Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</span> Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

You can even give some extra colors or style to this text-decoration:

```css
p span {
  border-bottom:1px tomato solid;
  box-shadow:inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 -2px turquoise
}
p {
  background:gray;
  }
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<span> Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</span> Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

You can also use the 3 kinds of decoration and mix them :

```css
.ovl {
  box-shadow:inset 0 2px tomato;
  color:yellow
}
.stt {
  color:#E9DFCC;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent calc(50% - 1px), white calc(50% - 1px), white calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px))
  }
.udl {
  color:turquoise;
  box-shadow:inset 0 -2px purple;
    }
.stt.ovl {
    box-shadow:inset 0 2px tomato,inset 0 -2px purple;
  }
p {
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<span class="ovl"> Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</span> Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.<br/> <span class="stt">Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi.</span> Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui.<br/><span class="udl"> Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</span> Praesent
  dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. <br/><span class="ovl stt udl">Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span></p>
```

For email client, you may use just old tags :

```css
u {
  color:red
    }
span {
  color:black;
  }
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<u><span> Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</span></u> Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Comment: That was awesome! Thank you this is helpful information and a great resource!  I believe I was able to create an underline with the border-bottom. Now, because this is code that will be rendered through email clients and web apps, should I be as concerned about browser support?  Normally, browsers are much more supportive of css elements than email clients. Right?

Comment: border-bottom on a span element is okay since ever, box-shadow and gradients is for younger browser, check it on http://caniuse.com/ to have a fast overview on where it is supported . border -bottom and top together can touch each other when wrapping a few lines,

Comment: @1Up also,  to strike  with another color and old browser , you may inbricate s/del and span: `<s><span>strike</span></s> or <del><span>strike</span></del>` and css test: `span {color:green;}`

Comment: So now I am running into a problem with the border-bottom.  Now, because the code will be rendered in email clients, the code is a series of tables with nested tables within the tables. Thus, from my knowledge, I had to place the header that I wanted underlined in a table but that effected the spacing.  The underline is a good 20px from the words I want underlined.  I set cellspacing and padding to zero, however, there is no change.

Comment: @1Up i added a snippet using the <u></u> tag wrapping a <span>text</span>, so it should render as wanted in email client, just add inline style for color :)